# Как вызвать функцию JS при работе программы?

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть функция отображения меню

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Menu1(id){
       var menu = document.getElementById('menu_' + id).style;
       menu.display = 'block';

    } 
</script>
```

и есть ее вызов при наведении мышкой.

```
<p class="dropdown_link_active" class="active" onmouseover="javascript:Menu1('<?php echo $category['name']; ?>')" >
<?php echo $category['name'] ?>
```

Нужно, чтобы меню отображалось сразу, а не после наведения мышки. Onload не работает.

Comment: А что вам мешает указать изначально видимость вашего меню через css?   `class="active  visible"`, где в css: `.visible {display: block;}`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я вам уже ответил [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33365444/236660). Дублирую ответ сюда:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
      Menu1('<?php echo $category['name']; ?>')
    });
</script>
```

Этот код вызовет функцию `Menu1` один раз, сразу после того, как документ будет загружен и разобран (parsed) браузером.